# Let $f(z) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^{n}$ has ROC $1$ and that only singularities on the circle $|z|=1$ are simple poles then ...

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

This question is from Ch-13 of Complex Variables with Applications by Ponnusamy and Silvermann.

> Suppose that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n $ has radius of convergence $1$ and that only singularities on the circle $|z|=1$ are simple poles. Then prove that sequence ${a_n}$ is bounded.

I am not able to understand how should I use the condition given which means that $f(z) (z- z_0) $ is analytic ( if $z_0$ is a simple pole) but I am not getting any direction and I need help?

So, please give some hints

Comment: Are you sure that "$|z|=1$ is a natural boundary" is included in the text of the exercise? Exercise 13.12.8 is similar to what you stated but does not include this assumption. It would mean that all points on the unit circle are singular points.

Comment: @Gary I am really sorry dude. I had mixed 2 questions. I beg for apologies.

Comment: This is mostly conjectural, but can you claim that (if there are finitely many such poles) $f(z)$ minus a finite linear combination of $(z-z_i)^{-1}$ with $|z_i|=1$ has no singularity on the disk $|z|=1$, hence is bounded there? Then, by Cauchy-type formulas, you can show that the coefficients of its power series expansion are bounded. But so are those for each $(z-z_i)^{-1}$, hence the conclusion...

Comment: @Mindlack Yes, if there are finitely many poles then this works. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860599/convergence-of-a-complex-power-series-at-the-radius-of-convergence

Comment: @Gary: ah, okay. I wasn’t entirely sure what was meant by “singularities” – but if it means “points around which there isn’t a holomorphic continuation” my argument works well indeed. With this meaning too, it’s not hard to see that there must be indeed finitely many poles...

Comment: @Gary: okay, but $-1$ is a singular point but not a pole, isn’t it?

Comment: @Mindlack You are correct.

Comment: There has to be finitely many such poles, otherwise they would accumulate on the disk giving a singularity which isn't a simple pole.

Comment: @CiaránÓRaghaillaigh Can you give a proof of "if poles are not finite in number, then there must be a singularity on disk which is not simple pole?

Comment: @Avenger If there are infinitely many poles on the circle, then by compactness they must have a limit point. Every neighborhood of that limit point will have infinitely many poles. However, a simple pole has a neighborhood around it where the function is holomorphic except for that simple pole. Thus the limit point is not a simple pole.

Comment: @CiaránÓRaghaillaigh I got it. Thanks!